# Question about Vi/Vim buffer

Tags: vim

i just started using Vi/Vim editor and while i m checking the list of active buffers for the buffer i m using i get this line:

```
1 %a + "buffername"                   line 16
```

What does `%a +` represent in the line?

I know that:

- 1 - represents the numbered buffer
- "buffername" - represents the named buffer
- line 16 - how many lines there are in the file under that buffer.

Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, there's a Stack Exchange dedicated to Vim: [vi.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`:h :ls`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Als):

```
:ls[!] [flags]
    Show all buffers.  Example:

            1 #h   "/test/text"             line 1 
            2u     "asdf"                   line 0 
            3 %a + "version.c"              line 1 

[...]
    Indicators (chars in the same column are mutually exclusive):
    u       an unlisted buffer (only displayed when [!] is used)
               unlisted-buffer
     %      the buffer in the current window
     #      the alternate buffer for ":e #" and CTRL-^
      a     an active buffer: it is loaded and visible
      h     a hidden buffer: It is loaded, but currently not
               displayed in a window hidden-buffer
       -    a buffer with 'modifiable' off
       =    a readonly buffer
       R    a terminal buffer with a running job
       F    a terminal buffer with a finished job
       ?    a terminal buffer without a job: `:terminal NONE`
        +   a modified buffer
        x   a buffer with read errors
```

So `%a +` indicates that that buffer is:

- the buffer in the active window
- an active buffer
- a modified buffer

Comment: Thank you very much Muru. That solved my question :)